# Ngrx createFeature() - State type issue

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

I'm trying to convert my reducer into createFeature() flow. I have strong tslint rules and it is required to add types to this api but it acts weird. I follow official docs https://ngrx.io/api/store/createFeature

My code is following:

```
export interface ProcessState {
    process: ProcessEntity | null;
    whatever: boolean;
}

const initialState: ProcessState = {
    process: null,
    whatever: false,
};

const processReducer: ActionReducer<ProcessState> = createReducer(
    initialState,
);

const featureConfig: FeatureConfig<'process', ProcessState> = {
    name: 'process',
    reducer: createReducer<ProcessState>(
        initialState,
    ),
};
const processFeature = createFeature<ProcessState, 'process'>(featureConfig);
```

It says that:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'FeatureConfig<"process", ProcessState>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FeatureConfig<"process", ProcessEntity | null>'.   Types of property 'reducer' are incompatible.     Type 'ActionReducer<ProcessState, Action>' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<ProcessEntity | null, Action>'.       Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.         Type 'ProcessEntity | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProcessState | undefined'.           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ProcessState | undefined'.`

And when I look into createFeature declarations it should work as expected.

Any ideas without using type any? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what's it worth, I would encourage to turn of the linter for this.
We're deprecating this signature, see the following PR for more info.
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/3756

```
#### Deprecated `createFeature` Signature with Root State (Introduced in v15.2)

The `createFeature` signature with root state is deprecated in favor of a signature without root state.

BEFORE:


interface AppState {
  users: State;
}
export const usersFeature = createFeature<AppState>({
  name: 'users',
  reducer: createReducer(initialState, /* case reducers */),
});


AFTER:


export const usersFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'users',
  reducer: createReducer(initialState, /* case reducers */),
});
```